# How to embed this C# code into HTML?

Tags: c#, html, flowplayer

I have a simple question, and I hope any one of you could help me out. My question is as follows:

I have defined some properties to run some videos in an HTML5 player [named Flowplayer], and the properties that am using are:

```
public string VideoSource; //it values are the source path of the video files
public string videoformat; //it values are e.g. video/webm and video/mp4
public int width; // The width of the player 
public int height; // The height of the player
```

**a)** Now here is the code which I really need your help in:

```
string.Format("<div style=\"width:{0}px;height:{1}px\" id='video1' class='flowplayer' data-swf='flowplayer.swf' data-ratio='0.4167'><video><source type='videoformat:{0}' src='VideoSource:{0}'/></video></div>", videoformat, width, height);
```

**Well, the above code doesn't work. I am pretty sure that the aforementioned text in the code is wrong (Especially everything inside the `<video>...</video>`) and needs to be fixed. So, Could you please help me in it ?**

**b)** Here is another way I used to use:

```
string.Format("<div style=\"width:{0}px;height:{1}px\" id='video1' class='flowplayer' data-swf='flowplayer.swf' data-ratio='0.4167'><video><source type='video/webm' src='http://myepiserversite/Global/WebmFileSample.webm' /></video></div>", videoformat, width, height);
```

**This second code way works fine, But this is quite impractical because it ONLY works with 1 single video format (video/webm) and 1 single video file (Hardcoded). I really want it to be more flexible and be able to take the values of both videoformat and videosource from the variables.**

So, My goal is to resolve point (**a**) and embed the C# code properly into the HTML tags.

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Are you trying to generate HTML from console app? If it is ASP.Net WebFroms/MVC there are better ways to output tags from code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's your original snippet 1:

```
string.Format("<div style=\"width:{0}px;height:{1}px\" id='video1' class='flowplayer' data-swf='flowplayer.swf' data-ratio='0.4167'><video><source type='videoformat:{0}' src='VideoSource:{0}'/></video></div>", videoformat, width, height);
```

Here is your snippet 1 reformatted to make it readable:

```
string.Format(
 @"<div style=""width:{0}px;height:{1}px"" id='video1' class='flowplayer' data-swf='flowplayer.swf' data-ratio='0.4167'>
     <video>
        <source type='videoformat:{0}' src='VideoSource:{0}'/>
   </video></div>", 
   videoformat, width, height);
```

This makes the mistake more obvious: you're referencing argument 0 more than once, and only used three of the values you need. Do this instead:

```
string.Format(
 @"<div style=""width:{0}px;height:{1}px"" id='video1' class='flowplayer' data-swf='flowplayer.swf' data-ratio='0.4167'>
     <video>
        <source type='videoformat:{2}' src='VideoSource:{3}'/>
   </video></div>", 
   width, height, videoformat, VideoSource);
```

Also, don't forget to assign the result somewhere. Finally, to condense it back to match the original:

```
string result = string.Format("<div style=\"width:{0}px;height:{1}px\" id='video1' class='flowplayer' data-swf='flowplayer.swf' data-ratio='0.4167'><video><source type='videoformat:{2}' src='VideoSource:{3}'/></video></div>", width, height, videoformat, VideoSource);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Joel for your prompt response.

Comment: Thanks Joel. Your code should work as it is logical, But the player shows unsupported format error message (Though it is NOT a format issue because the exact same file works when I pass it as hardcoded). The video format parameter is filled into a textbox as: video/webm => this value has to be filled inside videoformat:{2}- Is  the error because the value is 2 words and separated by slash? Also the width comes correct as it is filled in the textfied, but the height value becomes SO BIG it should be 300 px but as output it became 33554431 px ... What do you think about those two issues?

Comment: Hi again Joel, The 2 issues I reported were my mistake (Extra unhandled parameters). I now got it to work correctly based on your code. Thank you so much !

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?

```
string.Format("<div style=\"width:{0}px;height:{1}px\" id='video1' class='flowplayer' data-swf='flowplayer.swf' data-ratio='0.4167'>**<video><source type='videoformat:{2}' src='VideoSource:{3}'/></video>**</div>", width, height, videoFormat, VideoSource);
```

I just updated your string with substitution markers 0-3 and then matched up the arguments.

Comment: Thanks Peter. I tested your code and I get the same two problems that I commented on under Joel's answer. Please, Do you have a solution for those 2 issues ?

Comment: Hi again Peter, The 2 issues I reported were my mistake (Extra unhandled parameters). I now got it to work correctly. Thank you so much, I really appreciate your inputs!